# Do I need to purchase a trusted cert for offline environment?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, https, certificate

1. I have a webserver used self-sign cert which is not connected to internet and those connect to my webserver also have no connection to internet, in such environment, do I need to purchase a trusted cert? It was highlighted in VA scan.
2. Is internet connection required for browser to verify the trusted cert? Assumed I have purchased ssl cert for my webserver.

Comment: If you have control over the machines (or can make the users install your own CA in their trusted certificates) then a cert from a conventional CA isn't needed, neither online or offline.

Answer (score 7):

If the clients are truly offline, then a commercial cert won't work properly anyway, because the clients will fail when they try to look up the CRL for the cert issuer's CA.

SO no, if the entire environment has no internet connection, than a commercial cert will do you no good. Using manual certificate distribution or an internal CA would be better.

Comment: Most clients will not fail if they can't look up the CRL because they use soft-fail for CRL and OCSP.

Comment: I would say "few", not most. Most will fail.

Comment: @CryptoGuy: It depends on the application and business priorities.  If availability is paramount, it may be desirable to configure the application not to fail on a CRL check.  That could be a spectacular house of cards.  Certificate infrastructures are flimsy enough as it is without having some random heisenbug-like failure plaguing a system.  See: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/964.certificate-revocation-list-crl-verification-an-application-choice.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If environment is completely offline then there is no need of certificate as you won't be able to see any error without internet connection.

However, if you need one then would advise go with self-signed certificate for testing purpose as it would cost you zero bucks. But using self-signed certificate for testing purpose then it would not assure you that you won't be able to get any error.

Comment: *you won't be able to see any error without internet connection* incorrect. No internet connection doesn't prevent a system from comparing the cert with its trust store.